# How to find out non unique records?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
SELECT TRD.PKG_ID||'_'||TRD_CONT_NBR||'_'||LEG.TRD_LEG_NBR||'_'|| TRD.TRD_ID||'_'||CF.CURR_CODE||'_'||cf.cflw_date||'_'||CF.CFLW_TYPE_CODE
 ||'_'||CF.CFLW_STATUS_CODE as Surrogate_key 
 , CF.EFF_DATE, TRD.PKG_ID, TRD_CONT_NBR, TRD.SRCE_TRD_ID
 , LEG.TRD_LEG_NBR, TRD.TRD_ID, LEG.TRD_LEG_ID
 , CF.CURR_CODE, cf.cflw_date, CF.TRD_CURR_CASH_FLOW_AMT
 , CF.INT_RATE, cf.INT_RATE, CF.CFLW_TYPE_CODE, CF.CFLW_TYPE_GRP_CODE
 , CF.CFLW_STATUS_CODE 
from edw.extv_t_dim_trd TRD
 , edw.extv_t_trade_leg LEG
 , edw.extv_fact_cash_flow CF
where TRD.SRCE_TRD_ID = CF.SRCE_TRD_ID
  and TRD.TRD_ID = CF.TRD_ID
  and CF.SRCE_TRD_ID = LEG.SRCE_TRD_ID
  and CF.TRD_LEG_ID = LEG.TRD_LEG_ID
  and TRD.SRCE_SYS_CODE = 'WSS'
  and cf.SRCE_SYS_CODE = 'WSS'
  and leg.SRCE_SYS_CODE = 'WSS'
  AND TRD.TRD_STATUS_CODE <> 'CANCELED'
  AND LEG.INSTM_TYPE_CODE NOT IN ('FX', 'FX-OPTION')
  AND TRD.TRD_ACTV_TO_DATE >= to_date('04/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
  and TRd.TECH_TRD_FLAG = 'N'
  and cf.cflw_status_code = 'FINAL'
  and TRD.ACTV_FLAG = 'Y'
  and LEG.ACTV_FLAG = 'Y'
  and cf.actv_flag ='Y'
```

With the above query,  if add distinct in Surrogate_key I was able to find out the unique values but my problem is the overall record for the query is 3 million..  With distinct 2.5 million but I Would like to find non stop unique value  of. 5 million. So how can I achieve that?

And one more in some cases we were not having primary key in the table so I use to form Surrogate_key . Even that was also contains some duplicate values.  Future what kind of method if I need to use to avoid such problem.

Thanks, 
Srini

Comment: Please format your code properly and reduce the query to the core problem. Thank you.

Comment: Oracle people should learn the ANSI SQL to do joins. The where clause is a mess when jointures are done there.

Comment: @srini what do you like find? Duplicates of Surrogate_key? Because if that, maybe i can help you.

Comment: @GastonF. Exactly i want to find rest of the duplicate records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not undestand all your problem, but assuming that you want to search duplicates of **surrogate_key** then maybe this script will be useful:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(
  Surrogate_key VARCHAR2(100));

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('AAAA');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('ACAA');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('AAAA');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('AAAB');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('AAAA');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('ACAA');

/*HERE THE QUERY*/
SELECT T.Surrogate_key, COUNT(1) AS MATCHES
FROM TEST T
GROUP BY T.Surrogate_key
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

You can try this **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/da063/1)**.

**(EDITED 2013-07-15)**
Assuming that your query works, then try this (with this you can find the repeated rows):

```
SELECT T.Surrogate_key, COUNT(1) AS MATCHES 
FROM (
    SELECT TRD.PKG_ID||'_'||TRD_CONT_NBR||'_'||LEG.TRD_LEG_NBR||'_'|| TRD.TRD_ID||'_'||CF.CURR_CODE||'_'||cf.cflw_date||'_'||CF.CFLW_TYPE_CODE
     ||'_'||CF.CFLW_STATUS_CODE as Surrogate_key
    from edw.extv_t_dim_trd TRD
     , edw.extv_t_trade_leg LEG
     , edw.extv_fact_cash_flow CF
    where TRD.SRCE_TRD_ID = CF.SRCE_TRD_ID
      and TRD.TRD_ID = CF.TRD_ID
      and CF.SRCE_TRD_ID = LEG.SRCE_TRD_ID
      and CF.TRD_LEG_ID = LEG.TRD_LEG_ID
      and TRD.SRCE_SYS_CODE = 'WSS'
      and cf.SRCE_SYS_CODE = 'WSS'
      and leg.SRCE_SYS_CODE = 'WSS'
      AND TRD.TRD_STATUS_CODE <> 'CANCELED'
      AND LEG.INSTM_TYPE_CODE NOT IN ('FX', 'FX-OPTION')
      AND TRD.TRD_ACTV_TO_DATE >= to_date('04/01/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
      and TRd.TECH_TRD_FLAG = 'N'
      and cf.cflw_status_code = 'FINAL'
      and TRD.ACTV_FLAG = 'Y'
      and LEG.ACTV_FLAG = 'Y'
      and cf.actv_flag ='Y'
) T
GROUP BY T.Surrogate_key
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: i'm not allowed to create tables. i'm into ETL Testing

Comment: @SriniVasan then if you can't create tables, please try the new query I've posted maybe will be useful.

Comment: @SriniVasan please do not forget mark this post as useful. Thanks!.